# Overridable functions in Zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Consider the following two functions:

```
function slow_git_prompt_info() {
  if [[ "$(command git config --get oh-my-zsh.hide-status 2>/dev/null)" != "1" ]]; then
    ref=$(command git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || \
    ref=$(command git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return 0
    echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX${ref#refs/heads/}$(parse_git_dirty)$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX"
  fi
}
```

and:

```
function branch_name_only_git_prompt_info() {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
  echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX${ref#refs/heads/}$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX"
}
```

I would like to define **another** third function that, **when called**, overrides/defines the function `git_prompt_info()` in the main "namespace" to make it "point" to `fast_git_prompt_info`

E.g. something like:

```
# Pseudo-code:
function redefine_git_prompt_info() {
   git_prompt_info = branch_name_only_git_prompt_info
}
```

Is this at all possible with Zsh? If so, how?

Comment: `functions[git_prompt_info]=$functions[branch_name_only_git_prompt_info]`

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas That works great. If you write this as an answer I will definitely accept it!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function anywhere. To chain another function, just call it with the same parameters.

```
redefine_git_prompt_info () {
  git_prompt_info () { branch_name_only_git_prompt_info "$@"; }
}
```

If `branch_name_only_git_prompt_info` is later redefined, a call to `redefine_git_prompt_info` will call the new definition. If you want to copy the current definition, in zsh, you can do it easily thanks to the [`functions` array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-functions-2).

```
redefine_git_prompt_info () {
  functions[git_prompt_info]=$functions[branch_name_only_git_prompt_info]
}
```